# Trying to Return a Value From an IF Statement Without Creating a Circular Argument

Tags: apex

Let me give a general description of what I'm trying to do, which may help.

I am trying to create a formula where it will return the remaining dollar amount on a contract based off of how many remaining months there are on the contract. The problem I am running into is that with my current formula, it is continuing past 0 into negative amounts. My thought was to do something along the lines of nesting the IF statement below into another IF statement, but then I would assume it would create a circular argument. Ideally I would want it to return the value calculated if it were a positive amount, and return 0 if at 0 or a negative value.

I am sure that there will be more information necessary so please let me know how I can help you further. See below for the general formula I have so far to calculate remaining dollar amount on contract.

```
IF (DAY(TODAY()) <= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),14),
(Air_Time_Rate_c*ROUND((Contract_End_c-TODAY())/31,0)),
(Air_Time_Rate_c*ROUND(((Contract_End_c-TODAY())/31)-1,0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use MAX as a shorthand IF statement.

```
MAX(0,
IF (DAY(TODAY()) <= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),14), 
(Air_Time_Rate_c*ROUND((Contract_End_c-TODAY())/31,0)), 
(Air_Time_Rate_c*ROUND(((Contract_End_c-TODAY())/31)-1,0))))
```